# Finding GIT installer for Ubuntu

Tags: git

I just started using Ubuntu Linux for the first time. I know the GIT official site but not following which package to download and install the core GIT engine.

Comment: oh btw, is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you install from Synaptic Package Manager

Answer (score 5):

`sudo apt-get install git-core` will works

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install git-core` or with the Synaptic Package Manager

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it: `sudo apt-get install git-core` (in the *Terminal* application).